# What is the purpose of separating routes into individual modules with Node.js and Express?

Tags: node.js, code-organization, routing

My app uses Node.js and Express 4 and has the following code in the `app.js` file located in the root directory:

```
var express = require('express');

var index = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/users', users);
```

The `routes` folder in the root directory contains an `index.js` file with the following code:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    res.render('index');
});

module.exports = router;
```

The `routes` folder also contains a `users.js` file with the following code:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    res.render('users');
});

module.exports = router;
```

I'm new to Express and Node.js. It's my understanding that this structure causes browser requests to `domainName.com` to run the `index.js` file, while requests to `domainName.com/users` will run the `users.js` file, resulting in different views being rendered in the browser.

What is the purpose of organizing the code this way? (i.e. why is `app.use()` in `app.js` used to isolate each `router.get(path, callback)` into it's own respective module?)

Is the commonly-accepted practice to organize routes differently for a single page app versus a website consisting of mostly static text, such as a blog? If so, how?

Comment: I've removed your references to "best practices," because you didn't define what you meant by "best" in a way that is relevant to your specific design issues.  See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142353/why-is-asking-a-question-on-best-practice-a-bad-thing

Comment: In any event, the organization of routes and modules in this fashion is simply that: *organization.*

Comment: @RobertHarvey Why couldn't the 'router.get(path, callback)' just be included in the 'app.js' file? What is the benefit of separating that portion of the code into separate modules?

Comment: It's the same benefit that you would get by organizing any other system into separate modules.  If you don't believe this organization benefits you, then by all means: use one giant module for everything.

Comment: @Jackmc1047 I think they're expecting a real project to add significantly more code to each of those files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you only have two routes, it makes no sense to separate them in this way. However, when you consider a real application with many routes, it begins to make more sense.

**/routes/user.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var User = require('../models/user');

router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    res.render('users');
});

router.param('userid', function (req, res, next, userid) {
    req.user = User.findById(userid);
    req.userid = userid;
});

router.get('/:userid', function (req, res, next) {
    req.user.exec(function (err, user) {
        if (err) { return next(err); }
        res.render('user', {user: user});
    });
});

router.put('/:userid', function (req, res, next) {
    User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.userid, req.body, function (err) {
        if (err) { return next(err); }
        res.render('user-updated');
    });
});

router.delete('/:userid', function (req, res, next) {
    User.findByIdAndDelete(req.userid, function (err) {
        if (err) { return next(err); }
        res.render('user-deleted');
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Having all of that in app.js will get out of hand very quickly, even more so once you have more models than just `user`.

Also note that this isn't the only way to organize your routes/models/views nor is it the "best" way for all cases. You'll have you decide for yourself what will work best in each application.

---

Note, the code in the sample is of course all just sample code that probably won't work. My model methods were based off of mongoose model methods.